# In Cypress loop return true if condition satisfies, else return false after the iteration ends

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, ui-automation

I need to run a loop through multiple elements having the same CSS selector and return true if the element.text() matches with the string. If there is no match then return false at the end. 
I tried something like below but it didn't work:

```js
getProfilePresentOrNot(profileName) {
  var flag = 0;
  cy.get('li>div>div>span').each(($el,index,$list) => {
    if ($el.text().includes(profileName)) {
      flag=1;
    }
  });
  return flag;
}
```

This function always `returns 0` even though I can confirm that the condition in the if block satisfies.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: @JeremyKahan Yes, Iw ent through it. But since I am a beginner at it, I was not able to understand it and implement it for my use case. Any help to implement it in the code above would really be appreciated.

Comment: I'm working on it. I have had the same issue in protractor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@JeremyKahan is correct, it's like mixing synchronous and asynchronous code. The synchronous code always executes first.

Basically, you can see it by adding a couple of `console.log()`

```
function getProfilePresentOrNot(profileName) {
  var flag = 0;
  cy.get("li>div>div>span").each(($el, index, $list) => {
    if ($el.text().includes(profileName)) {
      console.log('Setting flag')
      flag = 1;
    }
  });
  console.log('Returning flag')
  return flag;
}
```

This will print in the devtools

```
Returning flag
Setting flag                // because cy.get(...).each(...) ran later
```

You could use a custom command

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getProfilePresentOrNot', (profileName) => {
  cy.get("li>div>div>span")
    .invoke('text')                                  // all text from all spans
    .then(allText => allText.includes(profileName))  // returns the result of .includes(...)
})
```

which must be used like this

```
cy.getProfilePresentOrNot('someprofilename')
  .then(isPresent => {  // true or false
    if (isPresent) {
      ...
    }
  })
```

or if you are ***absolutely sure*** that all `li>div>div>span` are present in the page, you can still use a function but switch to synchronous Cypress code (i.e jQuery).

```
function getProfilePresentOrNot(profileName) {
  const allText = Cypress.$("li>div>div>span").text()
  return allText.includes(profileName);
}
```

which can be called like this

```
const isPresent = getProfilePresentOrNot('someprofilename')
```

The custom command is safest because on a production web page there are lots of things that can fail your test because the element can't be found immediately, and Cypress asynchronous commands have built-in mechanisms to avoid the problems.

Comment: I like your use of the console logs to illustrate the issue.

Comment: So I am trying to use the second method. After calling the function using 
const isPresent = getProfilePresentOrNot('someprofilename')
how can I ascertain that the value of "isPresent" is "true". I tried using "expect" but I noticed that this line always executes before the "getProfilePresentOrNot" function gets called.